# How to assign users office365 licenses using groups with Microsoft graph and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a PowerShell script to assign users office 365 license based on group (security group). So, i have created app registration and assigned the required API permissions.

When I try to run my script, i get the error below

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $body -ContentType "application/jso ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Below is the entire script

```
$connectiondetails = @{

    # This ids and secret are present in the overview and certificate & secret page of our application in azure AD

    # Tenant ID here
    'tenantid' = ""

    # Application (client) ID here
    'clientid' = ""

    # Secret id here
    'ClientSecret' = "" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

}

$token = Get-MsalToken @connectiondetails
$tokenid_ = $token.AccessToken

# $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"

# $grp = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $tokenid_)}
# $grp


$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/ffbabc6f-aa87-40f3-8665-9d140e4a7adb/assignLicense"

$body = "{""SkuId"":""cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46""}"

# assign license call
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Method post -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $tokenid_)}
```

Permissions assigned to the app
[image]

I need assistance to know what am doing wrong. Thank you.

Solutions tried
[image]

Comment: Have updated the question with the snip showing the assigned application permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body for the request to add license requires `addLicenses` property with permissions `Group.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All`.

```
{
  "addLicenses": [
    {
      "skuId": "cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46"
    }
  ],
  "removeLicenses": []
}
```

PS

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/ffbabc6f-aa87-40f3-8665-9d140e4a7adb/assignLicense"

# create json object
$data = @{
    "addLicenses"    = @(
        @{
            "skuId" = "cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46"
        }
    )
    "removeLicenses" = @()
}

# convert to JSON-formatted string
$body = $data | ConvertTo-Json

# assign license call
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Method post -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $tokenid_)}
```

Resources:

[Group - assign licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Kindly see the snip in the question.

Comment: @Bernietechy Try to create json object and convert it to json, see updated answer

Comment: Hi @User2250152 the updated answer has worked. Thank you, a lot.